# Auto-vectorize shuffle instruction

Tags: c, sse, avx2, auto-vectorization

I'm trying to make the compiler generate the `(v)pshufd` instruction (or equivalent) via auto-vectorization. It's surprisingly difficult.

For example, presuming a vector of 4 `uint32` values, the transformation : 
`A|B|C|D => A|A|C|C` is supposed to be achieved using a single instruction (corresponding intrinsic : `_mm_shuffle_epi32()`).

Trying to express the same transformation using only normal operations, I can write for example :

```
    for (i=0; i<4; i+=2)
        v32x4[i] = v32x4[i+1];
```

The compiler seems unable to make a good transformation, generating instead in a mix of scalar and vector code of more than a dozen instructions.
Unrolling manually produces an even worse outcome.

Sometimes, a little detail get in the way, preventing the compiler to translate correctly. For example, the nb of elements in the array should be a clear power of 2, pointers to table should be guaranteed to not alias, alignment should be expressed explicitly, etc.
In this case, I haven't found any similar reason, and I'm still stuck with manual intrinsics to generate a reasonable assembly.

Is there a way to generate the `(v)pshufd` instruction using only normal code and relying on compiler's auto-vectorizer ?

Comment: And where is the question?

Comment: how to do generate `(v)pshufd` with normal code

Comment: Did you mean to use two different variable names in your example?

Comment: Good point ! could be any combination : having separate destination and source vector, or modifying the source vector directly. Whichever works.

Comment: My point was, if you're not modifying the source then your example doesn't do what you said it does.

Comment: That should not matter much. Transformation ABCD=>AACC does not imply that source must be modified. I'm perfectly fine if AACC is stored at a different location. I'm also fine if it overwrites ABCD. The only objective is to have this transformation done in a single vectorial instruction.

Comment: To me it seems like you're asking why your C code does not vectorize to a particular instruction. The answer, given that example, is your C code doesn't do the same thing that instruction does. Maybe I'm missing something. *shrug*

Comment: I know it doesn't quite answer the question, but what about using `__builtin_shuffle` and/or `__builtin_shufflevector` to at least speed up GCC/clang? Just be careful because ICC doesn't support `__builtin_shuffle` even though it will claim to be a version of GCC which does (or at least it didn't last time I checked). https://github.com/nemequ/simde/blob/master/simde/simde-common.h#L173 if you want a macro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Update: new answer since 2019-02-07.)

It is possible to make the compiler generate the `(v)pshufd` 
instruction, even without gcc's vector extensions which I used in a 
[previous answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54489707/4).
The following examples give an impression of the possibilities.
These examples are compiled with gcc 8.2 and clang 7.

**Example 1**

```c
#include<stdint.h>
/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        Yes            */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      No             */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      No             */
void shuff1(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b, int32_t n){
    /* this line is optional */  a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n; i=i+4) {
        b[i+0] = a[i+0];
        b[i+1] = a[i+0];
        b[i+2] = a[i+2];
        b[i+3] = a[i+2];
    }
}


/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        Yes            */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      Yes            */
void shuff2(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b, int32_t n){
    /* this line is optional */  a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n; i=i+4) {
        b[i+0] = a[i+1];
        b[i+1] = a[i+2];
        b[i+2] = a[i+3];
        b[i+3] = a[i+0];
    }
}
```

Surprisingly clang only vectorizes permutations in the mathematical sense, 
not general shuffles. With `gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem`,
the main loop of `shuff1` becomes:

```
.L3:
  add edx, 1
  pshufd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi+rax], 160
  movaps XMMWORD PTR [rsi+rax], xmm0
  add rax, 16
  cmp edx, ecx
  jb .L3
```

**Example 2**

```
/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        No             */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        No             */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      No             */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      No             */
void shuff3(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b){
    /* this line is optional */ a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    b[0] = a[0];
    b[1] = a[0];
    b[2] = a[2];
    b[3] = a[2];
}


/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        Yes            */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      Yes            */
void shuff4(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b){
    /* this line is optional */ a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);
    b[0] = a[1];
    b[1] = a[2];
    b[2] = a[3];
    b[3] = a[0];
}
```

The assembly with `gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake`:

```
shuff3:
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
  mov DWORD PTR [rsi], eax
  mov DWORD PTR [rsi+4], eax
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi+8]
  mov DWORD PTR [rsi+8], eax
  mov DWORD PTR [rsi+12], eax
  ret
shuff4:
  vpshufd xmm0, XMMWORD PTR [rdi], 57
  vmovaps XMMWORD PTR [rsi], xmm0
  ret
```

Again the results of the (0,3,2,1) permutation differs essentially from the (2,2,0,0) shuffle case.

**Example 3**

```
/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        Yes            */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      No             */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      No             */
void shuff5(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b, int32_t n){
    /* this line is optional */ a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 32); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 32);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n; i=i+8) {
        b[i+0] = a[i+2];
        b[i+1] = a[i+7];
        b[i+2] = a[i+7];
        b[i+3] = a[i+7];
        b[i+4] = a[i+0];
        b[i+5] = a[i+1];
        b[i+6] = a[i+5];
        b[i+7] = a[i+4];
    }
}


/*                                       vectorizes     */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem        Yes            */
/*   gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake        Yes            */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=nehalem      No             */
/*   clang -m64 -O3  -march=skylake      No             */
void shuff6(int32_t* restrict a, int32_t* restrict b, int32_t n){
    /* this line is optional */ a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 32); b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 32);
    for (int32_t i = 0; i < n; i=i+8) {
        b[i+0] = a[i+0];
        b[i+1] = a[i+0];
        b[i+2] = a[i+2];
        b[i+3] = a[i+2];
        b[i+4] = a[i+4];
        b[i+5] = a[i+4];
        b[i+6] = a[i+6];
        b[i+7] = a[i+6];
    }
}
```

WIth `gcc -m64 -O3  -march=skylake` the main loop of `shuff5` contains the 
lane crossing `vpermd` shuffle instruction, which is quite impressive, I think.
Function `shuff6` leads to the non lane crossing `vpshufd ymm0, mem` instruction, perfect.

**Example 4**

The assembly of `shuff5` becomes quite messy if we replace `b[i+5] = a[i+1];` 
by `b[i+5] = 0;`. Nevertheless the loop was vectorized. See also this [Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/dCsQr8) 
for all the examples discussed in this answer.

---

If arrays `a` and `b` are 16 (or 32) byte aligned, then we can use
`a = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(a, 16);` `b = (int32_t*)__builtin_assume_aligned(b, 16);` 
(or 32 instead of 16). This sometimes improves the assembly code generation a bit.

Comment: Ugh, with `-march=skylake`, gcc goes berserk with `vmovd` or `vextractps` to EAX, `vinsertps`. and `vpinsrd`.  https://godbolt.org/z/-bkA2G  clang still uses `vmovsldup` and `vpermilps` for the first 2, but for the one without native vectors clang still uses scalar like gcc.  Silly compilers.

Comment: Nice Trick !
Granted, it works, as shown in the assembly.
But the whole point of writing an algorithm using "normal" instructions, rather than specific ones, is 1- keep the code portable, and 2- allow arbitrary adaptation to target capability. For example, let the code convert to 256-bit for AVX or 512-bit for AVX512. Unfortunately, `__attribute__((vector_size(16)))` seems to make both these objectives difficult.

Comment: @Cyan: You are right. That is why I wrote: "*but probably it is not the way you are looking for*". I have made other attempts with "normal" instructions, but none of them were successful, unfortunately. Even a simple `for` loop, that swaps the even and odd entries, doesn't vectorize. But note that with `typedef float v16sf __attribute__((vector_size(64)));`, clang can even generate a `vpermps zmm0, zmm1, zmm0`. I'm surprised nobody else came with a better solution.

Comment: Compilers other than clang are often pretty crap at auto-vectorizing shuffles.  I haven't really tried to find an answer for this.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I was surprised that gcc performs better than clang actually, in these examples. But in general auto-vectorization of shuffles is rather unreliable indeed.